# Using AT TIME ZONE Time Zone Specifiers for GMT conversion

Tags: database, teradata

How to convert PST time(DST Included) to GMT using "AT TIME ZONE Time Zone Specifiers" ?

Answer (score 0):

GMT = UTC = 00:00?

```
select yourtimestamp at time zone '00:00'
select yourtimestamp at '00:00'
select yourtimestamp at 0
```

If you want to convert to a daylight saving time zone (DST)

```
select yourtimestamp at 'Europe Western'
```

Check the [manuals](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/db_ttu_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_112A/DateTime.087.008.html) for more details